# Prefill Stack Overflow ask page

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-overflow

I'm working on a website with programming video tutorials.

I want to provide to my users a way to ask questions on Stack Overflow if they have a problem following the tutorial.

I would love to link to the "ask" page on this site, while putting some data in a GET variable (like the tutorial title etc...), that data will be put in the question fiels to make the process seamless for the user.

It this possible on StackOverflow ? If so how? If not what are the provided integration possibilities that would help.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use SO for something like this. Create your own forum, or trust your users to be smart enough to use a tag, as this could very easily be used for spam.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well this *is* already supported, but I wouldn't recommend using it:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=my_title&tags=my_tags
```

Use with caution, as you'd hate for your users to be flagged as spam.

It is not, however, possible to pre-fill the body, as pointed out by [Nick Craver♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver) (a SO developer):

> Not publicly, no, it's only used by one internal mechanism and is secured.

Comment: Not OP, but: using this system, is it possible to prefill the body of the question using this method? I tried `&body=my%20body`, but that didn't work

Comment: @HobbitHole I've been testing around with different query params and so far it doesn't appear possible. It'd be great to hear a dev's comment on that, though.

Comment: @HobbitHole - not publicly, no, it's only used by one internal mechanism and is secured.

Answer (score 0):

I think that doing this is just going to lead to an unpleasant experience for all involved.

Having the question automatically titled and tagged might lead the user to think that Stack Overflow was the official support community for your video tutorials, when in fact it is not.

I see the following problems:

- Users see the auto filled title, so they don't provide any context to the problem
- Users requesting clarification, new videos, reporting errata, etc ..
- Users not tagging beyond the auto filled tags
- Users not looking for duplicates

Our question intake process has become *extremely* fine tuned over the years in order to help people realize that they *aren't* on a typical forum, and we put quite a bit in front of them to help them have a good experience. We plan to add even more just in time help in the future. Your idea *might* work for those that have prior experience on the site, it's new users that worry me.

What I recommend you do is make a support page. An example of an open source project that has successfully integrated SO as *one* of the possible places to get help is PhalconPHP, [as you can see](http://phalconphp.com/support) - they make it very clear what kinds of questions should be asked on the site. This could just be something that people can mouse over in order to see places where they could conceivably get help if you want to do something similar.

It's great that you want to send people to the site, but I think the way that you're contemplating going about it would not fulfill the goals you have in mind. Unless they were experienced with Stack Overflow, pre-filling the question form would almost certainly lead people to a negative experience.